# Ionic Menu button not appearing

Tags: angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ionicons

I created and ionic project using the command

```
ionic start sideMenu http://codepen.io/vialware/pen/ypoxd
```

I expected the app to be like what is shown below.

[image]
Nevertheless, when I run it something is missing, the menu button. It is being created I guess using in the header using this tag:

```
<ion-view title="'Welcome'" hide-back-button="true" left-buttons="menuButton">
```

[image]

I'm able to build and emulate the project without any errors and so I'm wondering whether I might have done something wrong and if anyone might have a hint on how to solve this problem (I'm new to both Ionic and AngularJS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this :

```
    <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
                <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
```

But don't forgot to put has-header to your content or your content will be behind this header bar

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
     // Content
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have that specific header, here's what your code should look like:

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
  <button class="button icon ion-navicon"></button>
  <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Note that the bar-positive class is only setting the blue color background on the header.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the change I made is, added attribute `enable-menu-with-back-views="true"` as below. Then sidemenu button and content is shown in all views.

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
```

Please refer below link:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuClose/

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your app? If you are just opening your index.html plainly on a browser it most probably won't work... Try running it using localhost (local web server).

Assuming this is true... You need to turn IIS Server on and run your site there

If you don't know how, you can try this tutorials below.

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZAbdmPrU4g

HOPE THIS HELPS :)